# How to Change from personal work organizational Account to service Account or Azure user-account in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Currently in my organization in Azure DevOps with email myname@mycompanyonmicrosoft.com
(individual work Account)

From my Azure portal, when i click on Azure DevOps Organizations , it takes me to Azure Devops which is
tie to my personal MS  work account, how can i setup azure devops following best practices so that its not link to an individual's account rather to something like a service or shared account.

Am just looking for someone to point me in the right Direction on how to setup Azure Devops for success while incorporating  best practices .

How can I fix that?